# The correct way to override WooCommerce product gallery from a plugin

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, templates, hooks

WooCommerce product page has image and thumbnails near it.

I'm making a plugin that overrides main image, thumbnails and lightbox (so I don't need any built-in classes).

My question is: what's the correct way to do this from a plugin?

For now I see two ways:

1) Override `product-image.php` template file via filter. But I'm not fully understand if it applies to main image, or thumbnails, or both.

```
add_filter( 'wc_get_template', 'modify_product_gallery_template', 10, 5 );
function modify_product_gallery_template( $located, $template_name, $args, $template_path, $default_path ) {

    if ( 'single-product/product-image.php' == $template_name ) {
        $located = '... my-gallery.include.php';
    }

    return $located;
}
```

2) Remove actions to apply my own:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'woocommerce_show_product_thumbnails', 20 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'my_plugin_show_product_image', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'my_plugin_show_product_image', 10 );
```

What's the best way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're wanting to replace all image markup with something custom, the best option is #2 - that way your new plugin controls everything relating to the gallery, and any future template overrides in WooCommerce will not affect it directly.

If it's just the default lightbox you want to remove you don't actually need to change markup or remove CSS classes; you can simply de-activate the feature. Thats explained here: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Enabling-product-gallery-features-(zoom,-swipe,-lightbox)

Comment: It is very good that we have an authoritative answer, and will be extremely nice if WC team will own the tag, but generally speaking answers that some important part of it is in an external resource are not considered great answers around here.

Comment: #1 worked well for me, but it would be sweet to have some understanding of "why" #2 is better.